# Grouping query and subquery items in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, subquery

I am trying to group my query so that my results only show once for each account number.  Below is the sql I am using.

```
`select top 10 c.svc, sum(c.tx_amt) as "Total Payments", d.fyear_name, d.fmonth_name, c.acctnbr_int,
(select iif(datediff("d",c.svc_dte,c.pst_dte)<=6 and c.trans_cd in ('0092001','0092051','0093201','0093204','0093212','0093601','0093652','0093653','0093654','0093655','0093701','0096316','0096351','0096366',
'0096405','0096407','0096408','0096409','0096422','0096452','0096455','0096456','0096459','0096473','0096474','0091551'),sum(c.tx_amt),0)) as "POS Payments"
from rptg.vwall_chg_tx_plus c
join rptg.vwdim_date d on c.pst_dte = d.day_date
where c.Pst_Dte > '09/30/2015' and c.Pst_Dte < '11/1/2015'
and c.Svc = '002'
and c.pt_acct_ctg_nme <> 'inpatient'
and c.trans_cd in ('0093101','0093102','0093151','0093152','0093251','0096302','0096303','0096304','0096305','0096306','0096307','0096308','0096309','0096311','0096312',
'0096313','0096314','0096322','0096343','0096352','0096353','0096354','0096355','0096356','0096357','0096358','0096359','0096361','0096362','0096363','0096364','0096367',
'0096372','0096375','0096380','0096381','0096382','0096383','0096392','0096398','0096399','0096426','0096454','0096458','0096477','0096478','0098353','0098354','0098400',
'0098401','0092001','0092051','0093201','0093204','0093212','0093601','0093652','0093653','0093654','0093655','0093701','0096316','0096351','0096366','0096405','0096407',
'0096408','0096409','0096422','0096452','0096455','0096456','0096459','0096473','0096474','0091551','0093254','0093272','0093751','0096395','0096406','0096410','0096412',
'0096413','0096451','0096457','0096472','0099201')
and c.AcctNbr_int in ('3215385349')`
```

The result is:
svc Total Payments  fyear_name  fmonth_name acctnbr_int POS Payments
002 -150.00 FY 2016 FY16 M4 3215385349  -150.00
002 -100.00 FY 2016 FY16 M4 3215385349  -100.00

But the result should be:
Svc POS Pmts    Total Pmts  FYear_name  fmonth_name AcctNbr_int Insrnc_Pyr_Cde
002 ($250.00)   ($250.00)   FY 2016 FY16 M4 3215385349  SELF PAY

When I try to group the items and sum(c.tx_amt) I get error messages about aggregates or subqueries not allowed in group by clause.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out.  Adding sum to the subquery provided me with the desired results.

(select ***sum***(iif(datediff("d",c.svc_dte,c.pst_dte)<=6 and c.trans_cd in ('0092001','0092051','0093201','0093204','0093212','0093601','0093652','0093653','0093654','0093655','0093701','0096316','0096351','0096366',
'0096405','0096407','0096408','0096409','0096422','0096452','0096455','0096456','0096459','0096473','0096474','0091551'),sum(c.tx_amt),0))) as "POS Payments"